# Delete all measurements

Tags: measurement, annotation

Is there a way to delete a bunch of measurements? I can't seem select them and Annotations Window is empty.

[image]

Comment: wait i just deleted them i think i went to Object Mode or from Edit Mode to Object Mode and they dissapeared. Not sure what i did but they are gone.

Answer (score 25):

When you clear measurements through *View > Annotations*, they don't vanish immediately.
Simply switch tools or modes and they will be gone.

*Changing tools or quickly tabbing into edit mode works*
[image]

Comment: Why is blender so finicky? I feel like they should hire a UX designer and give that person a lot of authority

Comment: amen. Im no expert in blender but its painful to do some things that are basic imo. For instance set the z value for all selected points to the same height ... booleans that dont destroy the model ... remove all measurements ... organizing materials ... so many things. Many things I do infrequently which I have to search google and by the time I have to do it again I cant remember where it was.

Answer (score 5):

To delete all the measurements select individual measurement and click ***x*** to delete each of them .While selecting don't click in the middle of those lines(It will only add an angle and if you click x it will only delete the angle) instead click on any end point.

It is a tedious job if you have many measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key deletes the measurements.

Comment: Esc does nothing, you can delete them with X by selecting them.